# Stream analytics join query not working - return 0 rows

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have two input files on my stream analytics. one is csv and another one is json. I just making join query on stream analytics but its not working.

This is my query

```
SELECT
    i1.Serial_No,i2.Customer_Id
FROM input1 i1
JOIN input2 i2
ON
  i1.Serial_No =  i2.Serial_No
```

Sample data

Json :
{
    "Serial_No":"12345",
    "Device_type":"Owned"
}

CSV :

"Serial_No,Customer_Id"
12345,12345

Please any one help me in this

Comment: Your query doesn't have any output; it only shows inputs (you have no `INTO` clause). Plus you haven't shown any sample data. So... a bit difficult to know what's going on (though my guess is the lack of `INTO`). Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Hi David , i find the solution. problem in comma delimiter is not working on stream analytics. i have created csv data using tab. Now my query is working fine with join. Thank you!

Comment: @Nagarajan.M Please summarize your solution as an answer to end this case.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tab delimiter is working]

[image: comma delimiter is not working]

Using join query on stream analytics comma delimiter is not working on CSV. But tab delimiter is working.